# Formatting CSS style for multiple tables on the same page

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to format two tables on the same page with different CSS styling, however, there is inheritance I'm unable to stop it.

For example, if I change the font color or size it changes it on both tables.

I have tried isolating the tables in CSS by giving them, unique classes.

```
table.table1 

table.table2
```

or

```
.table1

.table2
```

in both cases, it didn't help isolating the CSS individually.

This is an example of the issue I'm having:

http://jsfiddle.net/amlife180/e3xr7Lqb/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying classes to all table cells when you think you are applying them to a specific table.

eg.

```
table.table2 th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green !important ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The is saying apply the styles to table.table2 th AND also to all td elements. The comma says apply styles to both.

you need to change this to

```
table.table2 th, table.table2 td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green !important ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to get the effect you want. Also do the same for

```
table.table1  th, table.table1  td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it works, if you change it to the following. Just separate the `tr` and `th`.

```
table.table1 {
    border:none !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.table1  thead {

     border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;

}

table.table1  th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}


table.table1   td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table.table1  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d1d8e0
}





table.table2 {
    border:none !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;

}

table.table2 th{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green !important ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;

}

table.table2 td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green !important ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```